# the usage of "Except"

Tags: word-usage

I want to describe the market size of food market except seafood. For example, if entire food market is 10 billion and seafood market is 1 billion, the rest of the food market size is 9 billion.
In that case, if I say "The entire food market is 9 billion except seafood industry." Is the word "except" used correctly?

Comment: "The food market is 9 billion [what? Dollars? Kwasha? Yen?] not counting seafood."

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: That's help a lot and I am going to use this expression in future. As to currency, I just made up the number for an example, but yes I should add the currency.  Thank you very much Michael， I really appreciate your help~

Comment: It's definitely incorrect to just use ***except*** as in your example. At the very least it should be ***excepting the** seafood industry*, but imho even that isn't idiomatic unless you relocate it and use commas, brackets, or dashes to delineate it as a "parenthetical" element (in this case, ***syntactically***, but not ***semantically*** parenthetical). *The entire food market (excepting the seafood industry) is 9 billion.* Stylistically I'd still prefer ***not including*** over ***excepting***, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The entire food market is 9 billion, **not including** the seafood industry."

We use "except" and "other than" when a general statement doesn't apply to some portion of the group. For instance,

> My friends love beer, except Joseph.

This means, for each of my friends, it is true to say, "That person likes beer", but it's not true for Joseph.

So, if I say, "The entire food market is 9 billion **except** the seafood industry", it means *each thing* in the entire food market is 9 billion, except for seafood, which is some other number.

Comment: The food **market** is one category of thing, and the seafood **industry** is another.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: as to your latest comments, do you suggest that I substitue "seafood industry" for "seafood market"?